# When to create a custom operator in airflow?

Tags: python, design-patterns, airflow

So there is a use case where I want to check the size of file and if it more than the size of a configurable value (changes per file type as per business rule) , we would return true/false as a return value. This is just a use case to add some context and not exactly my question. Question is 'when to decide to create a customer operator vs just using python callable as it is trying to accomplish is small task

1. there is reusability gain in terms of using operator
2. Single class responsibility and better testing (unit test of operator )
3. Better maintainability
4. There are some future complexity expected in the operator

So do you think it is better to use a custom operator than a simple pythonoperator with python callable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a python callable to start something small that works. Or you can encapsulate  this in a python script/file so you can unit test it outside of airflow. This itself is a separation of responsibility by using airflow only for orchestration and not to contain business logic.